# How to Apply a Style of Copied Clip Board Text in Android

Tags: android, android-edittext, clipboard

I have Edit Text Which Contain Custom Fonts.When I **Double Click** on Edit Text, Text Will be Copied to **Clip Board** And When I Paste on Messaging App. or Other App. It Will Paste a Text Which Copied But **It Does Not Reflect a Font Style**, It Shows By Default Text Which Show in Image Below.

[image]

[image]

here is my sample code for setting Custom Fonts For Edit Text and Copy text to Clip Board From Edit Text.

```
String Style = "C.A. Gatintas.ttf";
    face2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/"
                    + style);
            edt2.setTypeface(face2);



@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

                        String text = edt2.getText().toString();
                        myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
                        myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Text Copied to Clip Board", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();

                        return true;
                    }
                });

        edt2.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }

        });
```

Comment: you cannot copy the EditText's font-style. The EditText in Message Application has its own font-style.

Comment: I apply Custom Font Style to Edit text that i want to Copy so that when i paste on messaging app. it will shown in Custom Style Format.

Comment: You copy the text. Font style is set to the EditText. How do you expect a font style to be copied?

Comment: It's impossible with raw text. You should try to copy html text or image of this text.

Comment: So,Then How to Copy Custom Font Style in Clip Board that's my Question.

Comment: check out this apk. "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bhimaapps.fancytextfree&hl=en" in that it Copy Stylish text from clip board and Paste with that Styelable Fonts in Other App.

Comment: @Rahul So where you able to achieve this?

Comment: Any solution worked? I'd like to copy text with styles, like all those apps.